# Scan assembly for classes that implement certain interface and add them to a container

Tags: c#, interface, containers

I'm missing something but not sure what it is. I would like to implement this method, so it scan's the assembly containing the provided type and add them to the container.

the problem is: How do i add the types that are returned from my query to the collection of scanners?

```
public TorrentScannerContainer AddFromAssemblyOf<T>()
        {
            TorrentScannerContainer current;

            lock (TorrentScannerContainer._padlock)
            {
                var assignableType = typeof(ITorrentScanner);

                var scanners = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
                    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                    .Where(t => assignableType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass).ToList();

                foreach (Type type in scanners)
                {
                    var scanner = type as ITorrentScanner;
                    TorrentScannerContainer.Current.Scanners.Add(scanner);
                }

                current = TorrentScannerContainer.Current;
            }

            return current;
        }
```

The TorrentScannerContainer.Current.Scannners is a collection of ITorrentScanner:

```
internal List<ITorrentScanner> Scanners { get; private set; }
```

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: What is the result? Is there an error?

Comment: I've updated my question. The problem is: How do i add the types returned from my query to the collection of scanners? I'm having a Type and need to add ITorrentScanner

Comment: Dont you need a dictionary with the interface and the type?

Comment: No, just the collection of ITorrentScanner

Comment: Nothing yet, need to adjust my code. Sorry for the inconvenions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem is you try to add types in a collection of ITorrentScanner. You should either have a list of types in scanners, or create an instance of the type :

```
foreach (Type type in scanners)
{
    var scanner = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ITorrentScanner;
    if(scanner != null)
         TorrentScannerContainer.Current.Scanners.Add(scanner);
}
```

Of course, this means your type has a default constructor. If this is not the case, then I don't know how to instanciate them... but certainly you do

Comment: This does the job, damn i was so close :-).